# Finding a sufficient statistic when density function is given

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

Let $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)^T$ be a simply sample of random variable $X$ whose distribution belongs to family $\mathcal{P}=\{ f(x; \lambda, \eta, \mu ), 0<\lambda, \eta <\infty, -\infty <\mu <\infty \};$ where density function is $$ f(x; \lambda, \eta, \mu )= \frac{\lambda^{\eta}}{\Gamma(\eta)}x^{\eta -1} e^{-\lambda(x-\mu)}, x\geq \mu.$$ I need to find a sufficient statistic of parameters $\eta$ and $\lambda$ when $\mu$ is known.

So O think that density function I can write like this $$ f(x)=\prod _{i=1}^n\big( \frac{\lambda^{\eta}}{\Gamma(\eta)} \big) x_i^{\eta-1}e^{-\lambda(x_i-\mu)}=\big( \frac{\lambda^{\eta}}{\Gamma(\eta)}\big)^n \big(\prod _{i=1}^n x_i \big)^{\eta -1} e^{-\lambda\sum (x_i-\mu)}.$$

The joint density of the sample takes the form required by the Fisher–Neyman factorization theorem, by letting
$$ W(X)=1$$  and $q(T; \theta)=\big( \frac{\lambda^{\eta}}{\Gamma(\eta)}\big)^n \big(\prod _{i=1}^n x_i \big)^{\eta -1} e^{-\lambda \sum ( x_i-\mu)} $ where $L_X(\theta)=q(T; \theta) *  W(X)$ is likelihood function. Then $T=(T_1;T_2)=\big( \prod_{i=1}^n x_i; \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \big)$ is a sufficient statistic.

Is this right or I made a mistake?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Gamma_distribution

Comment: Of course, you need to write down the joint density of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ (likelihood function) and use the Factorization theorem.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I just updated my question with my answer. Can you check if I did it right?

Comment: Exponent of $e$ should be $-\lambda \sum (x_i-\mu)$, so your answer changes a little. And $W(X)$ is strictly speaking an indicator variable $\mathbf1_{x_1,\ldots,x_n\ge \mu}$, inherently present in the joint density.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I do not understand what you mean..

Comment: Your answer is correct. I meant you could also say a sufficient statistic for $(\eta,\lambda)$ is $(\prod X_i,\sum (X_i-\mu))$ since $\mu$ is known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Density function I can write like this $$ f(x)=\prod _{i=1}^n\big( \frac{\lambda^{\eta}}{\Gamma(\eta)} \big) x_i^{\eta-1}e^{-\lambda(x_i-\mu)}=\big( \frac{\lambda^{\eta}}{\Gamma(\eta)}\big)^n \big(\prod _{i=1}^n x_i \big)^{\eta -1} e^{-\lambda\sum (x_i-\mu)}.$$

The joint density of the sample takes the form required by the Fisher–Neyman factorization theorem, by letting
$$ W(X)=1$$  and $q(T; \theta)=\big( \frac{\lambda^{\eta}}{\Gamma(\eta)}\big)^n \big(\prod _{i=1}^n x_i \big)^{\eta -1} e^{-\lambda \sum ( x_i-\mu)} $ where $L_X(\theta)=q(T; \theta) *  W(X)$ is likelihood function. Then $T=(T_1;T_2)=\big( \prod_{i=1}^n x_i; \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \big)$ is a sufficient statistic.